# Specific C++ notation for function arguments?

Tags: c++, syntax

This is a simple question, but I couldn't find the answer through searching online. I was trying to work through some leetcode problems to better my understanding of C++. I was wondering if someone could walk me through the meaning behind the creation of this function.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        
    }
};
```

I understand that public is used so that we can access ____ outside the Solution class, but I am not sure what exactly... it also looks like we are initializing a vector of integers named "twoSum" with the arguments of a vector of numbers and a target value... I was wondering what the meaning of the & is... etc. I guess a simple question would be can someone translate this block of code so that I can write my own versions for various problems (it seems like this is a constant block (or variation of a similar block) of code that is common throughout these leetcode problems).

Comment: *I was trying to work through some leetcode problems to better my understanding of C++.* Usually the wrong thing to do. Competition code is written to win the competition, not to be readable or even moderately educational. Half the job at Stack Overflow seems to be fixing the self-inflicted brain damage caused by trying to learn to program from competition code.

Comment: You should have a look at some good C++ learning materials as this is very standard c++ code. It declares a member function that has a return type of `vector<int>` and takes two arguments. The first is `vector<int>&` which is an lvalue reference to a `vector<int>` and an integer. Going into what those are and how the syntax works is the job of a good tutorial/book/any other educational resource

Comment: @SamVarshavchik He did ask a very specific programming questions. `I was wondering what the meaning of the & is`

Comment: @MartinYork You missed the "etc" and "can someone translate this block of code".

Answer (score 1):

The shown code snippet, defines a member function named `twoSum` that has the **return type** of `vector<int>` and has **2 parameters**. The first parameter named `nums` is an *lvalue reference to a non-const `vector<int>`* while the second parameter named `target` is an `int`.

> I was wondering what the meaning of the & is

The `&` in the first parameter `nums` of the member function means that `nums` is an *lvalue reference to a non-const `vector<int>`*. Meaning, the argument that will be passed to the `nums` parameter, will be passed **by reference** instead of passed by value. That is, inside the member function `twoSums`, the `nums` refer to the original `vector<int>` that is passed as an argument.

Also note that there should be a return statement inside the member function since the return type of the member function is non-void.